# Oracle SQL question: How to create periods based on a table of days

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table Calendar that contains days.
If, as an example, the Calendar contains all days in the period 2023-02-01 to 2023-02-28 except the days 4, 10 and 11.

I would like to write a SQL that returns the three periods without the missing days like:
2023-02-01 - 2023-02-03
2023-02-05 - 2023-02-09
2023-02-12 - 2023-02-28

I write in the title that it is an Oracle question since I guess it is necessary to use analytical functions, but I cannot find out how.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to get the actual intervals

```
with dates as (select trunc(sysdate,'yy')+level sd from dual connect by level<10
union all
select trunc(sysdate,'yy')+level+13 sd from dual connect by level<5
union all
select trunc(sysdate,'yy')+level+25 sd from dual connect by level<3
)
select *
from (select sd, lag(sd) over (order by sd) lg
from dates) match_recognize(
order by sd
measures first(sd) as start_sd, last(sd)+1 as end_sd
one row per match
pattern (e+)
define e as sd=next(sd)-1);

02/01/2023 00:00:00 10/01/2023 00:00:00
15/01/2023 00:00:00 18/01/2023 00:00:00
27/01/2023 00:00:00 28/01/2023 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you to got your result

```
SELECT 
    prev_day, date_col 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        date_col 
        , LAG(date_col) OVER(ORDER BY date_col) prev_day
    FROM 
        Calendar 
    WHERE 
        date_col BETWEEN sysdate - 6 AND sysdate -- spec period
) WHERE date_col - prev_day > 1
```